# SFML Temporary speed boost implementation

Tags: c++, game-engine, sfml

in my SFML game, I'm trying to implement a Speed Boost option, however I don't quite know how to do it, here is a fragment of my code :

```
//Speed Boosts movement and collision
          for(size_t i = 0; i < speedup.size(); i++){
              speedup[i].shape.move(-0.2,0);
              if(speedup[i].shape.getPosition().x <= 0 - speedup[i].shape.getGlobalBounds().width){
                  speedup.erase(speedup.begin()+i);
              }
              if(speedup[i].shape.getGlobalBounds().intersects(player.shape.getGlobalBounds())){
                  speedup.erase(speedup.begin()+i);
                  
                  //SPEED UP HERE
              }
```

Also, here's my player movement code:

```
 //Player Movement
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
            player.shape.move(0,-0.5);
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
            player.shape.move(-0.5,0);
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
            player.shape.move(0,0.5);
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
            player.shape.move(0.5,0);
```

Now, I'd like, upon collision of the player with the speed boost sprite, for the players movement speed to be temporarily increased, however I don't quite know how to do it, should I use some fore loop and sf::Clock set the time of the boost? I also don't know how to change the movement speed temporarily.

I'd like more of a push in the right direction, than a complete code, so please give me hints how to realize that function

EDIT:
Proposed Speed boost implementation, it crashes:

```
if(speedup[i].shape.getGlobalBounds().intersects(player.shape.getGlobalBounds())){
                speedup.erase(speedup.begin()+i);
                float etime = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
                while(etime<=10){
                    y_spd=2*y_spd;
                    x_spd=2*x_spd;
                }

            }
```

EDIT 2
I'm trying to figure out my timer so that it measures time from collision properly:

```
//Clock
     sf::Clock dclock;
     float dt = dclock.restart().asSeconds();
```

I declare this in my main(), I've tried doing it in many ways, none gives me proper time measurement.

```
//Speed Boost movement and collision
        for(size_t i = 0; i < speedup.size(); i++){
            speedup[i].shape.move(-5,0);
            if(speedup[i].shape.getPosition().x <= 0 - speedup[i].shape.getGlobalBounds().width){
                speedup.erase(speedup.begin()+i);
            }
            if(speedup[i].shape.getGlobalBounds().intersects(player.shape.getGlobalBounds())){
                speedup.erase(speedup.begin()+i);
                timer += dt;
               }
            }

        //SPEED BOOSTING THE PLAYER

        if(timer>=10){
            y_spd=3;
            x_spd=3;
            timer = 0;

        }
```

Comment: `sf::Clock` seems like a good idea to track the duration of the boost.  To change the player's speed, try pulling the current value (`0.5`) out to a variable that you can change when you collect the speed boost.

Comment: This is what I came up with, however the game crashes once player collides with speed boost, check edit

Comment: Are you by chance iterating over `speedup` when you call `erase`?  That can cause a crash because `erase` typically invalidates some iterators - you have to assign your loop iterator to the result of `erase`.

Comment: I've switched to an if loop, but I can't figure out how to properly measure time, check edit 2 for the code I'm using.